# Bad value for type timestamp postgres in talend

Tags: postgresql, datetime, timestamp, etl, talend

I have Greenplum input, TMAP and Greenplum output as my job design.
I have a Postgres input(Greenplum Input) wherein I using this postgres query:

```
to_char(to_date(EI.LAST_UPDATE_DATE,'yyyy-mm-dd'),'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

I link this Postgres input (Greenplum Input) to Tmap wherein I take tmap input: LAST_UPDATE_DATE as Date and pattern as `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`. On my tmap output I map a similar target output Greenplum with similar column and set the date and pattern as same ie Date and pattern as `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`. I link this tmap to a greenplum output.

I am getting an error of GreenplumInput:

> Bad value for type timestamp 11-NOV-2008.

How do I sort this error? Do I take the date input as string and then convert it to date? I tried it in tmap itself by taking tmap output as talendparsedate to that column, but it shows unparseable date.

Comment: what is your expectation for last_update_date column on greenplum side - is it a varchar column or you want to maintain it as date? if its still a date expected on greenplum side, you dont need to do to_char() in tpostgresinput component. Simple select the date as ei.last_update_date in your select and in schema use date as the column datatype and format as any of the available say yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss...similarly in your tmp, tgreenplum output keep same format and datatype for schema column last_update_date...you should not get any issue with this.

Answer (score 0):

The error message mentions this as timestamp input

```
11-NOV-2008
```

Which dies not match your pattern:

```
to_date(EI.LAST_UPDATE_DATE,'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

Either change the input to:

```
2008-11-11
```

Or the pattern in your function to:

```
to_date(EI.LAST_UPDATE_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

Comment: I changed the pattern to "to_date(EI.LAST_UPDATE_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY')" But Talend cannot take the input as DD-MON-YYYY as MON is not readable to Talend(TMAP). Also, I tried to change the pattern to  "to_date(EI.LAST_UPDATE_DATE,'yyyy-mm-dd')" , but the job is running in a loop.